# How to flatten exactly two dimensions of the nested list?

Tags: r, list, flatten

Suppose I have a list `a` built as follows:

```
a1<-list(1,2,list("X",10))
a2<-list("A",list("B"),"C")
a3<-list(list("D",list("E")),3.14)
a<-list(a1,a2,a3)
```

How can I transform `a` into this:

```
list(1,2,list("X",10),"A",list("B"),"C",list("D",list("E")),3.14)
```

I want a solution that works for arbitrary number of `a1, a2, a3... an`, not only for `a1, a2` and `a3` as in example above.

In Mathematica I would simply use `Flatten[a,1]`, but how does one do it in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unlist` with `recursive=FALSE`:

```
dput(unlist(a,recursive=FALSE))
list(1, 2, list("X", 10), "A", list("B"), "C", list("D", list(
    "E")), 3.14)
```

Answer (score 3):

`do.call('c', a)` will be faster then `Reduce('c', a)`. `unlist(a, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)` will be faster then `unlist(a, recursive = FALSE)`. `unlist` is the way to go in this case.

Would post as a comment but I dont appear to be able.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
Reduce("c",a)
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Is `unlist(a, recursive=FALSE)` what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is... it looks better than mine solution.